# Set bool property using attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

Is there a way to set a property value using attribute? In View Model i have a propety:

```
public bool HasAccess{get;set;}
```

and would like to do something like this:

```
[MyAttribute]
public bool HasAccess{get;set;}
```

And MyAttribute should set the value of HasAccess.  My question is how to build MyAttribute to where I will Set the value of HasAccess to what ever value is given to it inside the attribute.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, and I get the feeling you are deeply confused on what exactly an attribute is, and how to use it properly.  Tell us what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain clear, I am trying to accomplish the same thing the DefaultValueAttribute does which it sets the value of the properety the attribute is on

Comment: That's not how that attribute works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx "A `DefaultValueAttribute` will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes are associated with a *type*.  You find this one through Type.GetProperty() and PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes().  That doesn't help you set the property value of an *object*.  Unless HasAccess is static, it doesn't look it.  Or in other words, you won't be able to supply the value for the first argument of PropertyInfo.SetValue().

If you already have the object reference then it isn't a problem, use its GetType() method and pass the object to SetValue.  But that's code elsewhere, not in the attribute class.

Comment: Attributes are not just associated with a type, they're also associated with members (like this case), parameters, etc.  Heck, they're even valid on internal-only constructs like interface-impl table rows.

Comment: Okay, "type definition" then.  Means the same thing.

Comment: Attributes can also be applied to assemblies as well as types, which is why I was quibbling.  More technically, attributes can be associated with many different ECMA335 tokens, not just with the tokens associated with a type.

Comment: Well, you're right.  I don't know how to work that into the answer without confusing the stuffing out of the OP.

Comment: I did say I was quibbling.  I've been spending a lot of time in nitpicking discussions about ECMA 335 files and detailed descriptions of how various elements (including attributes) are encoded, so I'm hyper-sensitive :).

Comment: hehe, sounds like .winmd immersion :)